# AWS Glue - pySpark: spliting a string column into a new integer array column

Tags: amazon-web-services, pyspark, etl, aws-glue

I am trying to perform an ETL job on AWS using Glue and pySpark, but unfortunately, I'm really new to this.

For the most part I dont have any problem working with glue dynamic dataframe to perform applymapping and some of the other transformations that I must perform. But I am facing a problem with a particular column that I must convert from string to integer array. In this column, `value`, we have the datatype set as string that is infact an array of integers converted to string and separated by space, for example a data entry in the `value` column looks like `'111 222 333 444 555 666'`. I must convert this column to be an integer array so that my data is transformed into `'[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]'`.

How can I achieve this in AWS Glue and using pySpark? Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Split the `value` column by **`space`** using `split` function and cast to **`array<int>`**.

- (or) by using **`transform`** `(From Spark-2.4)` function and casting array elements as int.

**`Example:`**

```
df=spark.createDataFrame([('111 222 333 444 555 666',)],["value"])
df.printSchema()
#root
# |-- value: string (nullable = true)

#using split and cast as array<int>  
df.withColumn("array_int",split(col("value"),"\\s+").cast("array<int>")).\
    show(10,False)

#using transform function
df.withColumn("array_int",expr("""transform(split(value,"\\\s+"), x -> int(x))""")).\
show(10,False)
#+-----------------------+------------------------------+
#|value                  |array_int                     |
#+-----------------------+------------------------------+
#|111 222 333 444 555 666|[111, 222, 333, 444, 555, 666]|
#+-----------------------+------------------------------+

df.withColumn("array_int",split(col("value"),"\\s+").cast("array<int>")).printSchema()
df.withColumn("array_int",expr("""transform(split(value,"\\\s+"), x -> int(x))""")).printSchema()    
#root
# |-- value: string (nullable = true)
# |-- array_int: array (nullable = true)
# |    |-- element: integer (containsNull = true)
```

Comment: Thank you so much sir. I have used the split method that you mentioned and it works perfectly.